# split file with output file with numeric suffix but without begin zero

Tags: linux, bash, split

Suppose I have a file `temp.txt` with 100 lines. I would like to split into 10 parts.
I use following command

```
split a 1 -l 10 -d temp.txt temp_
```

But I got temp_0, temp_1, temp_2,...,temp_9. I want output like this temp_1,temp_2,..,temp_10.

From `man split`
I got

```
-d, --numeric-suffixes
              use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic
```

I tried to use
`split -l 10 --suffix-length=1 --numeric-suffixes=1 Temp.txt temp_`

It says `split: option '--numeric-suffixes' doesn't allow an argument`

Then, I tried to use
 `split -l 10 --suffix-length=1 --numeric-suffixes 1 Temp.txt temp_`

It says
`split: extra operand`temp_'`

The output of `split --version` is

```
split (GNU coreutils) 8.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Torbj�rn Granlund and Richard M. Stallman.
```

Comment: Computer scientists count from 0, get used to it.

Comment: Have you read the [split man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html)? In particular the `--suffix-length=N` and `--numeric-suffixes[=FROM]` options?

Comment: @kaylum. I tried to use `split -a 1 -l 10 -d 1  Temp.txt temp_`. But it shows error `split: extra operand `temp_' `

Comment: You need to use the long form of the arguments: `split -l 10 --suffix-length=1 --numeric-suffixes=1 temp.txt temp_`

Comment: @kaylum. I tried your method, but I got `split: option '--numeric-suffixes' doesn't allow an argument`

Comment: Either you are typing it incorrectly or you are using an odd version of `split`. As you can see for yourself the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) clearly states that that option does take an argument.

Comment: Ok, so you are indeed using an old version of split. Can't help you then as don't know what your version supports. But provide `split --version` in case someone knows how to do it with your version.

Comment: split(1) only supports parameters to the --numeric-suffixes option since release 8.16 (2012-03-26)

Answer (score 3):

> I tried to use split -a 1 -l 10 -d 1 Temp.txt temp_. But it shows error split: extra operand temp_' `

`-d` doesn't have an argument.  It should be written as you originally tried;

> `split -a 1 -l 10 -d Temp.txt temp_`

But, forgetting the syntax variations for a moment;

*you're asking it to split a **100** line file into **10** parts, with a suffix length of **1**, starting at **1***.

**^- This scenario is erroneous** as it is asking the command to process 100 lines and giving it fixed parameters restricting it to processing only 90 lines.

If you're willing to extend your allowable suffix length to 2, then you will at least get a uniform two digit temp file starting at 01;

`split -a 1 -l 10 --numeric-suffixes=1 -d Temp.txt temp_`
Will create: **temp_01** thru **temp_10**

You can actually negate the `-a` and `-d` argument altogether;

`split -l 10 --numeric-suffixes=1 Temp.txt temp_`
Will *also* create: **temp_01** thru **temp_10**

If for some reason this was a fixed and absolute requirement or a permanent solution (i.e. integrating to something else you have no control of), and it was **always** going to be an exactly 100 line file, then you could always do it in two passes;

```
cat Temp.txt | head -n90 | split -a 1 -l 10 --numeric-suffixes=1 - temp_
cat Temp.txt | tail -n10 | split -a 2 -l 10 --numeric-suffixes=10 - temp_
```

Then you would get **temp_1** thru **temp_10**

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw out a possible alternative, you can accomplish this task manually by running a couple of loops. The outer loop iterates over the file chunks and the inner loop iterates over the lines within the chunk.

```
{
    suf=1;
    read -r; rc=$?;
    while [[ $rc -eq 0 || -n "$REPLY" ]]; do
        line=0;
        while [[ ($rc -eq 0 || -n "$REPLY") && line -lt 10 ]]; do
            printf '%s\n' "$REPLY";
            read -r; rc=$?;
            let ++line;
        done >temp_$suf;
        let ++suf;
    done;
} <temp.txt;
```

Notes:

- The test `$rc -eq 0 || -n "$REPLY"` is necessary to continue processing if either we've not yet reached end-of-file (in which case `$rc eq 0` is true) *or* we have reached end-of-file but there was a non-empty final line in the input file (in which case `-n "$REPLY"` is true). It's good to try to support the case of a non-empty final line with no end-of-line delimiter, which sometimes happens. In this case `read` will return a failing status code but will still correctly set `$REPLY` to contain the non-empty final line content. I've tested the `split` utility and it correctly handles this case as well.
- By calling `read` once prior to the outer loop and then once *after* each print, we ensure that we always test if the read was successful *prior* to printing the resulting line. A more naïve design might read and print in immediate succession with no check in between, which would be incorrect.
- I've used the `-r` option of `read` to prevent backslash interpolation, which you probably don't want; I assume you want to preserve the contents of `temp.txt` verbatim.

Obviously there are tradeoffs in this solution. On the one hand, it demands a fair amount of complexity and code verbosity (13 lines the way I've written it). But the advantage is complete control over the behavior of the split operation; you can customize the script to your liking, such as dynamically changing the suffix based on the line number, using a prefix or infix or combination thereof, or even taking into account the contents of the individual file lines in `$REPLY`.